# Getting undefined value. Javascript / React / mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, undefined, sitemap.xml

Why am I getting "Cannot read property 'cityLocation' of null" on createSiteMap function? Only the {propertyOwner} prop has an undefined value.

However, I am able to console.log(propertyOwner) and I am getting values.
Here are the results of the console logs:

2 608432995a21dc4d28bc8748 sg

4 608434915a21dc4d28bc8762 my

2 608fc2e15a21dc4d28bc886f jp

2 60937f3b5a21dc4d28bc88f6 usa

```
import { api } from '@helpers/api'
import { BASE_URL } from '@helpers/config'
import Slugify from 'slugify'
import { generateAuthHeaders } from '@helpers/authHeaders'
import { API_TOKEN } from '@helpers/config'

const url = BASE_URL

const createSitemap = (listings, date) => `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <sitemapindex xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 
    http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  
      ${listings
        .map(({ id, propertyOwner, listingName }) => {
          return `
              <sitemap>
                <loc>${`${url}rooms/for-rent/${id}/${Slugify(propertyOwner.cityLocation, { <<<--------------
                  lower: true,
                  strict: true,
                })}/rentalbee-at-${Slugify(propertyOwner.codeName, {
                  lower: true,
                  strict: true,
                })}/room-for-${Slugify(listingName, {
                  lower: true,
                  strict: true,
                })}`}</loc>
                <lastmod>${date}</lastmod>
              </sitemap>
            `
        })
        .join('')}
  </sitemapindex>
`

class SitemapId extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps({ res, query }) {
    const allRooms = await api.get(
      '/listings',
      {
        headers: generateAuthHeaders(null, 'application/json', API_TOKEN),
      },
      { params: { page: query.id } }
    )

    const date = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]

    allRooms.data.listings.map(({ listingName, id, propertyOwner }) =>
      console.log(listingName, id, propertyOwner.cityLocation)  <<---------------------
    )

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
    res.write(createSitemap(allRooms.data.listings, date))

    res.end()
  }
}

export default SitemapId
```

Comment: Apparently some listings don't have a `propertyOwner`

Comment: propertyOwner has 3 properties all of which are required. It's not possible to have an empty propertyOwner.

@toptalent can you tell me the solution. my brains not working atm :/

Answer (score 1):

instead of this:

```
console.log(listingName, id, propertyOwner.cityLocation)  <<---------------------
    )
```

Try to test this

```
console.log(listingName, id, propertyOwner[id].cityLocation)
```

Clue: last parameter is same as original object in map function

```
propertyOwner <=> allRooms.data.listings
```

Comment: Now, I got error when console logging propertyOwner[id].cityLocation. cityLocation is undefined

Comment: When I do 
allRooms.data.listings.map(({ listingName, id, propertyOwner }) => console.log(propertyOwner)

I get {
  _id: '5f02a42378f25c0d3bf9b7c3',
  propertyName: '816 Valencia',
  cityLocation: 'sg',
  codeName: 'Valencia',
}

When I do 
allRooms.data.listings.map(({ listingName, id, propertyOwner }) => console.log(propertyOwner.cityLocation)

I get Cannot read property 'cityLocation' of null